# Audio crackling as soon as power is on

Tags: audio, motherboard

A month ago I noticed that my 7-year old desktop computer started having audio issues: the sound is crackling, even when no sound is playing. You can hear it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I1GoAvno2CyxmXp9KN4ws5Zv3IAdjHdX/view?usp=sharing).

After a while, it became more and more noticeable so I decided to invest in an external sound card, thinking that it was probably due to the low-quality integrated Azalia codec on my Gigabyte motherboard. The Creative Sound Blaster Omni Surround 5.1 external sound card that I bought was even worse!

Usually the sound is OK for a few minutes after a cold boot, then it gradually starts to crackle to the point where it becomes unbearable. After that, even if I go in the BIOS menu, I can hear the noise. To me this means the issue is hardware-related.

Things I've tried, to no avail:

1. different headphones and speakers
2. different wall sockets
3. different audio cables
4. removed all USB, ethernet cables
5. shutdown the wifi signal
6. disabled all unnecessary options in BIOS

I suppose the motherboard (Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3H-B3) is to blame ? I know 7 years is a lot in the world of computer tech, but still, I bought that motherboard because it supposedly had high-quality ultra-durable components!

Anything else I should try before I buy a new computer ? (I don't think I'll be able to replace *only* the motherboard since it's too old)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by that sound, you probably have a Ground Loop.

you can check the solutions on the wikipedia page to see what may be applicable. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity)#Solutions

Answer (score 0):

I live in an old building so it doesn"t really surprise me that the electrical wiring is rubbish! I used an extension cable and plugged the main power cord from my desktop computer to another wall socket in a different room of my apartment, and, lo and behold, no more interference !

As a workaround, it's great, but now I need to figure out how to get rid of the interference on the wall socket that is closest to my computer, because I can't leave the extension cable lying around in the middle of the room ! I was going to purchase ferrite bead chokes (such as [this](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B01MG8GQ1F/?coliid=I2ZIQMM0T2ND3T&colid=S6EMLSW9QUXB&psc=0&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it)), I hope they will solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a generic answer before realizing that you had self-answered after identifying that the source is electrical noise from your power connection.  Those ferrite chokes are a cheap thing to try, but if they don't solve the problem, here are a couple of other things to look at.

- The fact that you found an outlet with clean power suggests a bad electrical connection somewhere in the path feeding the problem outlet.  If you don't own the building, you may have limited access to the wiring, but you could at least check the wiring that is accessible in your unit.  For safety, wear gloves when doing the suggested steps, below.

  Verify that the bad outlet has good electrical connections.  Try jiggling the wires connected to the problem outlet to see if that generates more noise.  If the outlet has push-in wire connections and you find a bad connection, remove the wire, strip off a little more insulation, bend it into an open loop, and fasten it to the screw terminal for a better connection. If only one outlet is a problem, try replacing it, especially if you can exacerbate the noise by jiggling the plug.

  Outlets are daisy-chained, so a bad connection could be somewhere else in the run.  Check other outlets for a similar problem.  In every electrical box with a problem outlet, try jiggling wires connected with wire nuts to see if a connection isn't tight (increase in noise). If you find a bad connection, clean up the wires, twist them into a good, tight mechanical connection, and replace the wire nut.

  If you don't feel confident doing this yourself, delegate it to an electrician or handyman.
- If you can't identify the source, a solution would be to use an online-type UPS (it always provides power from the battery, and the power input just charges the battery).  They tend to be expensive, though.

Comment: Well, I tried clip-on ferrite chokes and it didn't help one bit. The thing that surprises me is, when I tried to remove the ground loop between my audio amplifier and my computer, the only setup that works is when I plug each in 2 distant wall sockets. I thought that plugging them on the same power strip would solve the ground loop but it seems to exacerbate it!
I don't really feel confident checking the wall sockets & wire connections, especially since I'm only renting.

Comment: I've seen some surge protector/voltage regulator power strip with built-in EMI/RFI protection but I have no idea if they would be helpful in my situation. They do cost much less than a UPS though !

Comment: @geoced, a good power supply in your computer should filter out most of the electrical noise.  But components like the capacitors age and deteriorate.  You mention that it's 7 yrs old.  If you have or can borrow a laptop, see if you get the same level of noise when it's plugged in.  If you're planning to start replacing expensive parts (new motherboard or PC), try replacing the power supply.  it's a relatively inexpensive part, pretty easy to replace, and the most likely component to make a difference for this kind of problem.  Those power strips aren't likely to help with this problem.

Comment: The desktop's PSU is a Corsair 80Plus Platinum certified AX760, which comes with a 7-year warranty. I don't think I would be able to justify an RMA though. And at 150€, it's not exactly cheap! 
I'm also considering using a [PAC SNI-1 Noise Isolator](https://www.amazon.com/PAC-SNI-1-Noise-Isolator/dp/B000K50HJE/)

Comment: So I tried a Ground Loop Isolator and it was even worse than without ! In the end, it doesn't look like it's a ground loop issue then, as I can hear the crackling/humming/buzzing sound even when I disconnect my amplifier and plug in my headphones straight into the computer. If I choose another wall socket, it's gone. So I guess @fixer1234 is probably right: it's an electrical wiring/outlet issue...